# Test Page not showing up inside a wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I tried to display a test page `localhost/wordpress/test.html` inside my wordpress installation.

However, even though the page exists in this location wordpress simply displays the `File Not Found Page`.

How can I fix this and get my `localhost/wordpress/test.html` to show up?

Comment: Are you certain that you have the url correct?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

It was a wordpress theme redirect inside the .htaccess file